# How does anonym.to work?

Tags: javascript, redirect, http-referer

How does this website manage to blank the referer. All other referer blanking service seem to just cloak the referer. This one however manages to make google analytics believe that the user typed in the website.

I can't seem to figure out how they're doing it.

Ex: http://www.anonym.to/http://google.com

I don't even see the javascript code on their page that redirects it. I think it may be some sort of trick where they use google analytics to trigger some javascript code.

Comment: Here is the code used on their site that the previous commenter left. http://pastebin.com/sTVv8SBj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://google.com">`

It doesn't blank the referer. It changes it to the `anonym.to` URL.

Comment: Looks like it is just a meta refresh. Seemed to have missed that. Thanks!